# Error fetching data from youtube in xml format

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch youtube videos using Youtube Data API URL. Whenever i paste the URL directly in the address bar, it perfectly shows the result. But whenever i try to use that URL in `simplexml_load_file()` function, i get errors. I cannot figure out what is going on.

This is how i am doing this.

```
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat";

$output = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am getting this error message.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 23

Notice: simplexml_load_file(): send of 38 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 23

Notice: simplexml_load_file(): send of 25 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 23

Notice: simplexml_load_file(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 23

Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 23

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat" in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 23
```

I tried to use `file_get_contents()` function it also gives error.

```
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat";    
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
```

I get these errors using above code.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 15

Warning: file_get_contents(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 15
```

I also tried to use `simplexml_load_string()` function it also gives error.

```
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat";
$output = simplexml_load_string($url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

The above code gives me these errors.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 14

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 14

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in J:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\tube.php on line 14
```

I am using XAMPP v3.2.1 to run my script.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried running your code at [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tru-da2) and it seems to run fine. I'm thinking it might be an environment issue

Comment: I am on localhost server xampp. Is it possible to make it work with localhost?

Comment: Works fine on WAMP, too... Try file_get_contents(), and simplexml_load_string()

Comment: I edited my post. Please have a look. I tried `file_get_contents()` and also `simplexml_load_string()` but i kept on getting errors.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I'm not seeing a XAMPP v3.2.1. The latest version I see is 1.8.3 [XAMPP Download Link](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for all platforms. So my suggestion is try using a more up to date version of your environment.

Comment: do you have a firewall working? is so, check if it's blocking your connections.

Comment: Actually its XAMPP 1.8.3. When you run it and check the control panel, it shows v3.2.1. It comes up with `PHP Version 5.5.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check that remote file access is enabled, read the PHP manual page about [Using remote files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php).

After that, and if your firewall is not blocking connections, almost any option that you tried should work. But, in any case, here you have one using simpler commands, or at least simpler concerning what is working internally. Just a good old [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

```
// initialize variables
$url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/cat';
$content = false;
$handle = false;

// open the url/file
$handle = fopen( $url, 'r' );

// get the content from streaming
$content = stream_get_contents($handle);

// close the file reading session
fclose( $handle );

var_dump( $content );
```